# HOUR Function works as a formula but not as VBA code for 24:00

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a procedure that I thought was working last time I checked it but apparently it is not.  The problem I am having is with 24:00 and the hour check.  Yes a classic problem apparently.  When entering 24:00 and I use =hour(A1) where A1 has 24:00 in it, I get the answer of 0, and that part I am ok with.  I even have some other code that says if timehour = 0 then timehour = 24 and I carry on from there and all is peachy.

Today when I went to enter my 24:00 and used the hour function in VBA it returned run-time error '13': Type mismatch instead of 0.

## SET UP

Cell E4 and E5 in excel has validated data list for the user to pick from in a drop down that ranges from 01:00, 02:00, 03:00, ..., 24:00. All formatted as text.  If the user has selected 12 hour clock in set up then the times are listed 1:00 AM, 2:00 AM, 3:00 AM, ...,  11:00 PM, 12:00 AM.

## CODE

```
Private Sub Set_Work_Hours()
    Dim setStartHour As Integer
    Dim setEndHour As Integer
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    
    'setting the worksheet to be working with
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Daily")
    sht.Activate
    
    'hardcode location of start and end times from daily sheet
    setStartHour = Hour(Cells(4, 5).Value)
    setEndHour = Hour(Cells(5, 5).Value)
        
    Call Display_Work_Hours(setStartHour, setEndHour)
    
End Sub
```

I get the error at setStartHour or setEndHour when I select 24:00 from the list.
In another cell in the spreadsheet, I had the formula =HOUR(E4) and =HOUR(E5) and they both return 0 when 24:00 is selected.

Why is the VBA version of HOUR not returning zero?

Clarification on the question.
Why am I getting two different results from excel formula to VBA function?

## My work around

```
Private Sub Set_Work_Hours()
    Dim setStartHour As Integer
    Dim setEndHour As Integer
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    
    'setting the worksheet to be working with
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Daily")
    sht.Activate
    
    'hardcode location of start and end times from daily sheet
    If Cells(4, 5).Value = "24:00" Then
        setStartHour = 0
    Else
        setStartHour = Hour(Cells(4, 5).Value)
    End If
    If Cells(5, 5).Value = "24:00" Then
        setEndHour = 0
    Else
        setEndHour = Hour(Cells(5, 5).Value)
    End If
    
    Call Display_Work_Hours(setStartHour, setEndHour)
    
End Sub
```

Comment: 24:00 is not a valid time. The clock stops at 23:59. You need to use 00:00 instead.

Comment: if its not a valid time why does the excel formula return 0 instead of an error? And I do agree that excel uses a 00:00 to 23:59 clock.  What I am asking is why am I getting two different results.

Comment: Excel and VBA handle dates differently. Try this formula: `=HOUR("67:00")`. There's no 67 o'clock but Excel happily returns 19. (Hint: 67 Mod 24 is 19)

Comment: thanks for that explanation Kyle I thought they would have handle them the same.  I was obviously wrong with the ASSumption.

Comment: @Kyle put that up for the answer about the hours being handles differently and I will mark that as accepted answer.  For my situation I need 24 so I handle things in a slightly different fashion that allows me to leave 24:00 as an option in the user entered time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just expanding upon my comments. Excel stores dates and times as a serial number. The integer portion of the serial number is the number of days since 1/1/1900, and the decimal portion is the hours.

When you use hours as a string (e.g. "24:00"), Excel converts it to a serial number, in this case `1.0`, or `1/1/1900 0:00`. VBA does not implicitly convert invalid times like this, which is why you were seeing an error. The correct way to represent `"24:00"` in VBA is `"00:00"`.

Comment: and then you need to work the middle ground between the way the user thinks and the way the program deals with stuff.  hence why I need to keep the 24:00 in the list then convert it to a way the computer will deal with it.

Comment: See my comment. Please.

Answer (score 0):

As a general suggestion, why don't you just run all of your DateTime variables in UNIX time on the backend, and just simply convert to a user-readable date on the spreadsheet?

This way no errors!!

**Convert from human readable date to epoch**

```
DateDiff("s", "01/01/1970 00:00:00", time field)
```

**How to get the current epoch time**

```
DateDiff("s", "01/01/1970 00:00:00", Now())
```

Comment: Primarily because I did not know such a thing exsited.

Comment: Hopefully this helps. Shoot a comment at me if you need other ideas or suggestions